# retrieving whois data from jsonwhoisapi.com using api, c#

Tags: c#, api

I'm trying to connect to [jsonwhoisapi.com](http://jsonwhoisapi.com) to drag down some `whois` data, but am having no luck. Has anyone done this or done something similar and can help spot my folly? I've never done an api connection using `HTTP` headers.

I've basically copied this from a post online where it was apparently working, but the following dies at `GetResponseStream`.

```
    public static void WebRequest()
    {
        string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://jsonwhoisapi.com/api/v1/whois?identifier=google.com";
        try
        {
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webRequest.Headers.Add("userid:apikey");
                using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                    {
                        var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Response: {0}", jsonResponse));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, it didn't format nicely here. Hmm, strange.

Comment: You need to add 4 spaces before the first line of your code to format it properly. I can't do it since it says the edit has to be at least 6 characters long. Also, please include the exception you get.

Comment: It dies at the following line and jumps to catch without giving an error, hmm.


using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

Comment: *jumps to catch without giving an error* - That's not possible. Step further inside catch block and it must populate `ex`.

Comment: You've inspired me all.. it currently just bombs and doesn't populate ex, but if I execute the following: System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse()

.. then I get a 401 - which corresponds with authentication, so there's something wrong with my account or the header string used. Does anyone use this service successfully? 

I've tried the following without luck, and yes they are populated with the data they've sent me, and not the placeholder data i've put here:
webRequest.Headers.Add("user", "12345:apikey");
webRequest.Headers.Add("12345:apikey");

Comment: Are you adding the header in the format: {customer_id}:{api_key}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you'll have to replace 'apikey' with your ApiKey string, and userId with your CustomerId string.

Direct quote:

> With every request you must send the [customer ID:API key] pair to authenticate - both pieces of information can be found when logged in to you account.

Chances are you might have to encode the auth request using the instructions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol

> Client side:
>
> When the user agent wants to send the server authentication
>   credentials it may use the Authorization field.
>
> The Authorization field is constructed as follows:
>
> 1. The username and password are combined with a single colon. (:)
> 2. The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence.
> 3. The resulting string is encoded using a variant of Base64.
> 4. The authorization method and a space is then prepended to the encoded string, separated with a space (e.g. "Basic ").
>
> For example, if the browser uses Aladdin as the username and
>   OpenSesame as the password, then the field's value is the
>   base64-encoding of Aladdin:OpenSesame, or QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l.
>   Then the Authorization header will appear as:
>
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l

e.g. Something like:

```
webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userId, apiKey)))));
```

Comment: "I've tried the following without luck, and yes they are populated with the data they've sent me, and not the placeholder data i've put here: webRequest.Headers.Add("user", "12345:apikey"); webRequest.Headers.Add("12345:apikey");"

Comment: The instructions on the website are unclear, however it looks as though you'll need to encode your request header before sending it.

Comment: If it's basic auth then you **will** need to convert it to a Base64 string first, `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("userid:apikey"))`

Comment: Exactly this. ^

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks all, especially Kris. His provided string seems to have done the job.